# Testing with $http.backend in Angular

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following controller:

```
(function () {
angular.module('cacApp')
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope, $location, geonames) {
        $scope.browseCountries =

            function (path) {
                $location.path(path);
            };

        geonames.countries()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.countries = response;
            })
    })
}());
```

and have set up the following tests for it:

```
describe("mainController", function () {
var _geonames, _location, _scope;

beforeEach(module('cacApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $injector, $httpBackend) {
    _geonames = $injector.get("geonames");
    _location = $injector.get("$location");
    _scope = $injector.get("$rootScope").$new();
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    spyOn(_location, "path");

    $controller('mainController', {
        $scope: _scope,
        $location: _location,
        geonames: _geonames
    })

}))

it("should equal a length of 250", function () {
    var url = 'http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=steveyz';
    var httpResponse = [{}];
    httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, httpResponse);
    expect(_geonames.countries.length).toBe(250);
})

})
```

The "$scope.countries" response from running geonames.countries() returns an array of 250 objects, and a $scope.countries.length of 250.

I want to test to verify that the length of the response is actually 250 in my code. But when I run the test currently, I get the error "Expected 0 to be 250."

Is there a specific reason why my result is showing 0 instead of 250?

Comment: You are mocking the get call and telling it to respond with an httpResponse that you set up as [{}]. Also, I don't see where the "countries" variable is being set on the geonames dependency. Are you meaning to check the countries property on the scope?

Comment: `geonames.countries` appears to be a function. Did you mean `_scope.countries.length`?

Comment: @Phil I tried that first but got "Cannot read property "length" of undefined"